# How to give a signal saying "This is the background paragraph" in the beginning of a paragraph?

Tags: introductory-words

In a cover letter, I have a paragraph where I explain my educational background, and right at the beginning, I want to explicitly state that "This is the background paragraph".

**How can I do that?**

For example, would the followings work and sound natural?

> To briefly explain my background, I have started my university education ...

or

> If I am to explain my background briefly, I have started my university education ...

Comment: "My educational background is" is a clear enough signal to start a topic sentence. It is more concrete and will probably end up being more succinct in the long run to start "I am a junior at Princeton majoring in mathematics ..."

Comment: @JeffMorrow so, are you saying something like "My educational background is that I have started ..." ?

Comment: @JeffMorrow I am also trying to be sound professional and competent with my English skills.

Comment: Why not just make a section with its title being the first words of the paragraph, in bold: "**My [educational] background.** I have started my university education ..."

Comment: You are asking about style, which is a matter of opinion. Personally, I feel that getting to the meat of the matter directly is the mark of good exposition. But others feel that verbose circumlocutions prove that a person has spent a lot of time in school.  It is a bit scary to think that both opinions may simultaneously be correct. If you are dealing with the typical Human Relations Department, the probabilities do favor the idea that they will mistake number of words for ability to communicate clearly.

Comment: @YellowSky not possible

Comment: @JeffMorrow I really like being concise, but I think a short signalling makes the text much easier to navigate.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Yes, it is opinion based, I need examples of such signalling sentences; I would appreciate if you could give your own, and comment on mines

Comment: Are you still at university?? [have started]

Comment: @Lambie yes; haven't formally graduated.

Comment: Take it from me, just use: I am currently in my first-year of law school etc. Forget the term **educational background** here. You do not have enough items in the bank for that. And you are not in human resources, either.

Comment: @Lambie thanks for the encouragement

Comment: Just keep it simple. :)

Comment: @Lambie I am writing a cover letter for a visa application, and one of the purposes is to show my English skills. I wrote all the letter trying to be simple and coincise, but I still want to signal in the beginning of a paragraph, becasue it really gives an idea about what to expect from each paragraph.

Comment: If you really feel the necessity for an introduction, I already suggested one. "My educational background is ..." You could then introduce other paragraphs with similarly concise introductions, e.g., "My employment history is..." If anyone intelligent is reading your application, they will be interested in substance rather than style. Busy people do not like having their time wasted.

Comment: @JeffMorrow good point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for this.  Just say

> I have started my university education

or

> I am in my first year of a law degree

or similar.  We know that you are talking about your education because you talk about your education.

(It would be different if you were giving a spoken presentation because lots of signalling is better in that context)

If you decide to ignore this advice, a short titling phrase "My educational background:  I have started my university..."

(And general advice: don't try to *impress*.  Keep it simple. The best grammar is the grammar that nobody notices)